# Get User Details from Id of user in Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, controller, laravel-7, friend

I have been using a composer package **laravel-acquaintances** and have connected it up to my profile. I have also managed to befriend users, my issue is once I try to get all friendships it doesn't allow me to show it based off each users, username or even ID.

I will present the code I presume is important below, please let me know if I have missed anything out.

> web.php

```
Route::get('/followers/{$user->}', 'AcquaintancesController@index')->name('acquaintances.index');
```

> AcquaintancesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AcquaintancesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $friends = $user->getAllFriendships();

        return view('acquaintances.index',[
            'friends' => $friends
        ]);
    }

}
```

> acquaintances/index.blade.php

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="acquaintances">
                    <div class="row pt-5">
                        <ul>{{$friends}}</ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

> view on site

[site error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBfBk.jpg)

I have tried to use a foreach;

  {{$friends->user->username}}

... however that didn't work

I also tried a few other options that I assume were not the best. Please I would appreciate the help.

Comment: My Laravel is rusty, but how did you do the foreach? Similiar to this? ```@foreach ($friends as $friend) <ul>{{{ $friend->user->username }}</ul> @endforeach```

Comment: Also, your route is wrong. Need to fix this: ```{$user->}```

Comment: @Fly_Moe yeah pretty much, also I was testing something out as I sent it. But I forgot to correct it, thank you.

Comment: that isn't an error you are showing, that is the JSON serialized version of what ever `$friends` is ... what are you expecting to be showing when you try to echo `$friends`?

Comment: When i echo friends, i want to be able to be able to show the users username instead of the the data shown.

Comment: so you want a string that contains the username of all the users in `$friends`?